# how to show if a sequence is conv or div in a region.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can someone help me with this:

Let $b≥ 0$ and let ${a_n}_{n∈N}$ be given by:

$a_{n+1}=ba_n$

where $a_0 = 1$ find the values of b, where the sequence is either convergent or divergent. If it's convergent, find the limit.

I found that for $ b ∈ [0;1[$ $a_n \rightarrow 0$ 
and for $ b=1, a_n \rightarrow 1$
and for $b>1, a_n$ is divergent.
But I don't know how to show it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Exhibit what the terms are and use the properties of limits to evaluate. For example, 
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} 
&= 
ba_n \\
&=
b(ba_{n-1})\\
&=
b^2 a_{n-1}\\
&\ \vdots\\
&=
b^{n+1} a_0\\
&=
b^{n+1}.
\end{align}
If $0\leq b<1$, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1}
=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b^{n+1}
=
0
\end{align}
The other cases work similarly.